# How to roll back in git and start again (keeping the history and the merges in between)

Tags: git

I have read a lot about `git revert` but I am not sure what really applies on this situation.

- In a project I realised I made a mess :-)
- I want to start again from a specific old commit
- In the meantime, I have pushed to github (but not made any release) and made several merges in between
- I would like to keep the history to eventually pick up or at least read individual commit diffs of what I am going to revert

Comment: Why not push what you have now up to another branch, then just hard reset the branch you're on back to that commit and force push?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to keep a backup branch on your current state, then reset the branch and force push.

```
A---B---C <<< master <<< HEAD

git branch backup-before-cleaning
git reset --hard A
git push --force origin HEAD

  B---C <<< backup-before-cleaning
 /
A <<< master <<< HEAD
```

That being said, let's mention this alternative : the plumbing counterpart to `commit` known as [`commit-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) :

```
A---B---C <<< master <<< HEAD

git reset --hard $(git commit-tree -m "Return to A" -p $(git rev-parse HEAD) $(git rev-parse A^{tree}))

A---B---C---D <<< master <<< HEAD
```

where `D` has the exact same tree as `A`, but you won't need to force-push anything, and all these commits are still in history for later inspection.